# Using BitmapRegionDecoder to tile a large image

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm currently attempting set a large image (1800x1800) as an overlay on a Google MapView. I've figured out how to tile it, but I'm not quite certain as to how to place each tile in the proper place. I'm using BitmapRegionDecoder to chop the larger image into several 100x100 tiles. I'm assuming that I'll use a larger `Rect` object as the frame for the larger image, but I'm not quite certain as to how to place each smaller image in its proper place inside the frame.

```
Rect outerFrame = new Rect(0, 0, 1800, 1800);
            try {
                asset = this.getResources().getAssets().open("foo.png");
                decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(asset, false);

                for (int y = 0; y < 1800; y += 100)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 1800; x += 100)
                    {
                        Rect innerTile = new Rect(x, y, x + 100, y + 100);
                        Bitmap region = decoder.decodeRegion(innerTile, null);
                        // Need something here
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: While using the the `outerFrame` `Rect` object would be nice, it is by no means required. I just want to get this thing to work.

Comment: @jzafrilla Unfortunately, I ended up using Bing Maps instead.